# OpenMP activation on geany

Tags: compiling, gcc, geany, parallels

I am new to parallel programing and C, and was wondering how to active openMP on geany or another C program on linux?
It is a simple hello world i am trying to make:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <omp.h>

    int main()
   {
      #pragma omp parallel
      {
         int ID=0;
         printf("hello(%d)",ID);
         printf("world(%d) \n",ID);
      }
   }
```

But when compile i get some warnings, and can imagen i havent activated or set my compiler correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- OpenMP g++ option missing while compiling, with `-Wall` you should see this message:

  ```
  warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
         #pragma omp parallel
   ^
  ```
- In command line, add `-fopenmp`

  ```
  g++ -fopenmp -Wall openmp_test.cpp
  ```
- Using Geany:

  1. Create a new project
  2. Go to Project → Properties → Build tab
  3. Add `-fopenmp` to C++ compile & build commands, respectively:

     ```
     g++ -fopenmp -Wall -c "%f"
     g++ -fopenmp -Wall -o "%e" "%f"
     ```

  [image: geany project: c++ build options]

**Reference:** [Wikipedia - OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)